# ANDROID: How to display data from an ArrayList<LinkedHashMap>?

Tags: android, sqlite, arraylist

So I wanted to be able to put multiple rows of data from an `ArrayList` on `TextView`.

This is my code to display:

```
public void displayScores(){

    ArrayList<LinkedHashMap<String, String>> list = db.getAllUsersWithScores();
    for(LinkedHashMap<String, String> map : list){
        //I had to check if my arraylist had any data first

        Log.d("displayScores", "name: " + map.get("username"));
        Log.d("displayScores", "score: " + map.get("score"));
    }
}
```

And here is my XML file.This is where I intend to display the data from the method above:

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/container_scores"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="top">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:id="@+id/txtName"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtScore"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText,PrivateResource"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
         />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:id="@+id/txtScore"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textSize="24sp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

If I have left out any relevant piece of code, do let me know.

Comment: What exactly is your problem? Build the string that you want to show in the `TextView` out of the data. Call `setText()` on the `TextView` with that string.

Comment: If you are trying to accomplish what I think you are, you are going to need to create a `ListView`.

Answer (score 0):

Just call the setText() method on your text views as follows:

```
 TextView tvName = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtName);
 TextView tvScore = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtScore);
 tvName.setText("name: " + map.get("username"));
 tvScore.setText("score: " + map.get("score"));
```